# Vanilla JavaScript equivalent of jQuery(…).parent().nextAll(selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to have a vanilla JavaScript selector (without using jQuery) to get the same selection as shown below:

```
$('[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]').parent().nextAll('input[type=text]')
```

Can someone please help me? I’ve been struggling with it.

Comment: Try looking at the jquery source code. Jquery is just a collection of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `nextAll` method in DOM as far as I know, so it is a bit tricky to do that without using jQuery.

We can use a generator to iterate and filter `nextElementSibling` like this:

```js
function* myNextAll(e, selector) {
   while (e = e.nextElementSibling) {
       if ( e.matches(selector) ) {
          yield e;
       }
   }
}

let e1 = document.querySelector("[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]").parentElement;

let siblings = [...myNextAll(e1, "input[type=text]")];
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use `document.querySelector('[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]')` to select the starting-node.
- Get with `parentElement.children` all the siblings from the parent-node (including the parent itself).
- Iterate through the siblings until the parent-node is founded.
- Look for all other siblings if they are INPUT-nodes and from type text (=1).
- Collect them in an array.

For demonstration iterate over the result and change the background via test-class.

If you want try: https://jsfiddle.net/7p8wt4km/2/

```js
let result = [];
let par = document.querySelector('[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]').parentElement;
let sibling = par.parentElement.children;
let found = false;
for (let i=0; i< sibling.length; i++) {
    if (!found && sibling[i] ===par) {
        found = true;
        continue;
    } else if (found) {
        let sib = sibling[i];
        if (sib.nodeName !== 'INPUT' || sib.nodeType!= 1) continue;
        result.push(sib);
    }
}

result.forEach(el => { el.classList.add('test');});
```

```css
.test { background: green; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Sibling 0
  </div>
  <div>
    Parent
    <div data-automationid='pictureupload_1'>
      pictureupload_1
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='text'>
  <div type='text'>
    Sibling 2
  </div>
  <input type='test'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code get with index element

```
const getIndex = (node, groupNode) => {
    return [...groupNode].indexOf(node);
}

Element.prototype.nextAll = function(){
    var allChildren = this.parentNode.children;
    var index = getIndex(this, allChildren);
    allChildren = [...allChildren].filter((item) => {
        return getIndex(item, allChildren) > index;
    });
    return allChildren;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The normal `jQuery` selector function and the `parent` method should be clear:

```js
document.querySelector("[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]").parentNode
```

`nextAll` doesn’t currently have a vanilla JavaScript equivalent, but we can make one out of native DOM methods.
There are two ways of approaching it:

1. Select all children first, then filter all matching siblings after a certain element, or
2. using loops.

---

### 1. Select all children first, then filter all matching siblings after a certain element

Getting the set of siblings can be partially achieved with `.parentNode.children`.
But don’t worry about selecting the parent element itself, because filtering by DOM order is easy.
This uses [`Node.prototype.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) and [`Element.prototype.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
I’ve also included some [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that if `parentReference === document`, `parentReference.parentNode.children` won’t throw an error.
It defaults to an empty array, then.

```js
const selectParentMatchingNextSiblings = (jQuerySelector, siblingSelector) => {
    const parentReference = document.querySelector(jQuerySelector).parentNode;
    
    return Array.from(parentReference.parentNode?.children ?? [])
      .filter((element) => parentReference.compareDocumentPosition(element) & Document.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING && element.matches(siblingSelector));
  };

selectParentMatchingNextSiblings("[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]", "input[type=text]");
```

#### Alternative way with Ranges

The [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) can also be used for document order comparison.

```js
const selectParentMatchingNextSiblings = (jQuerySelector, siblingSelector) => {
    const parentReference = document.querySelector(jQuerySelector).parentNode,
      nextSiblings = document.createRange();
    
    nextSiblings.setStartAfter(parentReference);
    nextSiblings.setEndAfter(parentReference.parentNode?.lastElementChild ?? parentReference);
    
    return Array.from(parentReference.parentNode?.children ?? [])
      .filter((element) => nextSiblings.comparePoint(element, 0) === 0 && element.matches(siblingSelector));
  };

selectParentMatchingNextSiblings("[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]", "input[type=text]");
```

Note that this one won’t work with `"html"` as the first selector.

### 2. Using loops

```js
const selectMatchingNextSiblings = (jQuerySelector, siblingSelector) => {
    const parentReference = document.querySelector(jQuerySelector).parentNode,
      result = [];
    let currentElement = parentReference.nextElementSibling;
    
    while(currentElement){
      if(currentElement.matches(siblingSelector)){
        result.push(currentElement);
      }
      
      currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
    }
    
    return result;
  };

selectParentMatchingNextSiblings("[data-automationid=pictureupload_1]", "input[type=text]");
```

This should be self-explanatory.
The options from the other answers are also fine.